# Having trouble matching up argument types between C++ and Boost::Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, boost-python

I'm working on creating a C++ to python interface for an API where I'm not allowed to modify a significant portion of the C++ to obtain my interface.

I've chosen Boost::Python to use as my bridge from C++ to python.  I've defined the following portions of my BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE:

Start of my C++ portion:

```
using namespace boost::python;

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(sandman_lib) {

    class_<manblock::ManDriver>("ManDriver", init< ... >())

    scope sandprogression  = class_<SandProgression>("sandprogression");
    def("api_create_sand_c_side_from_cfg_file", api_create_sand_c_side_from_cfg_file);
}
```

From my interpreter, my use of this interface is as follows:

```
>>> import sandman_lib
>>> SAND = sandman_lib.sand_progression()
>>> SAND
<sandman_lib.sandprogression object at 0x7ffff7eaa998>
>>> SAND.api_create_sand_c_side_from_cfg_file("path_to_my_config_file")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
Boost.Python.ArgumentError: Python argument types in
    sandprogression.api_create_sand_c_side_from_cfg_file(sandprogression, str)
did not match C++ signature:
    api_create_sand_c_side_from_cfg_file(char const*)
```

Of course, over in the "sandprogression" scope, we have the prototype of this function we are trying to use above, it is defined as:

```
extern "C" void api_create_sand_c_side_from_cfg_file(const char* cfg_file_name);
```

I would have assumed certain types are automatically convertible between C++ and Python, but apparently this isn't the case.  I've been pouring over the boost documentation to try and understand how to simply explicitly setup the mapping, but I can't seem to grasp how it's done.

Answer (score 0):

`sandman_lib.sandprogression.api_blah("path")` should be used instead of `sandman_lib.sandprogression().api_blah("path")`. Look at [example on boost.org](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/python/doc/html/reference/high_level_components/boost_python_scope_hpp.html#high_level_components.boost_python_scope_hpp.example).

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't notice that error before until I compiled again.  Your latter suggestion does the trick there, but I still get the ArgumentError where     the function call does not translate from str to const char* automatically.